# How can I use xxx.scala.html in Play2.0 framework Controller

Tags: html, playframework, playframework-2.0, render

I am a fresh man, using play2.0 framework. Now I have a trouble to use xxx.scala.html. In Eclipse I added a xxx.scala.html, but I cannot use "xxx.render()" function to render my html.

Now I create a form1.scala.html in view package. I want to render this html in controller like this "return ok(form1.render());". But it cannot. Why I cannot?

I have checked Play-Sample(example: 'form' application). In this application controller class, he used form1.scala.html, form2.scala.html, summary.scala.html and so on defend by himself.It's Ok. But I cannot use like this.

Answer (score 0):

`views` is a regular Scala/Java package, but when the template compiler runs it adds a 'html' package under that which it places the compiled templates in. So the source `app/views/myTemplate.scala.html` results in the function `views.html.myTemplate`

The view templates are functions themselves, not classes or objects, the filename becomes the function name, there is no `render()` method.

So if you have the file app/views/myTemplate.scala.html you will be able to use it like this:

```
Ok(views.html.myTemplate())
```

or

```
import views.html.myTemplate
Ok(mytemplate())
```

Comment: Thank you for your time of explaining for me. I have solved the problem. When I add a new html, I should excute play eclipse and fresh the app on Eclipse.